# Pandas : Get Data from a csv file irrespective of Header position

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have csv files which I have to make **dataframes** with `panda`.
usually the files are in format like this:

```
Days    Page Impressions    Visits  Bounces
2012-12-15  692041  87973   31500
2012-12-16  602356  78663   29298
2012-12-17  730902  99356   37436
2012-12-18  730071  97844   37199
2012-12-19  774964  110446  43858
2012-12-20  419256  44592   13961
2012-12-21  320966  33692   10076
2012-12-22  200992  18840   5170
```

The problem I am facing is that sometimes CSV files come like this:

```
SomeName ABCD           
Account: AccountHolder Name         
Report Author: Analysis         
Description: Some variable length description       

Pivot           

Pivot           
Days    Page Impressions    Visits  Bounces
2012-12-15  367143  69147   30222
2012-12-16  334675  63702   28040
2012-12-17  409260  77171   33642
2012-12-18  427765  78221   33575
2012-12-19  434781  79850   34300
2012-12-20  463448  81361   34501
2012-12-21  447964  81897   35242
2012-12-22  368477  70352   31014
2012-12-23  321891  61973   27521

Time of Calculation: 2013-03-15 02:14:58
```

How can I get only the data that is associated in the columns of **Days,    Page Impressions,   Visits, Bounces**

I know I can do `list(my_dataframe.columns.values)` to get the header names but it doesnt work on CSV file type-2.

Is their any Existing Pythonic way for doing this in pandas or something ?
Thanks

Comment: probably easiest to write a separate script to clean the data, skipping rows without valid values.

Comment: a dynmaic way would be to try to read the csv and if there are errors keep incrementing `skiprows` param until it works, unfortunately this won't be foolproof in which case you'd have to parse the result or parse the headers first before determining how many rows to skip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the files in two passes. First enumerate the lines in the file to get the row where the headers are. Pass that row number to the csv parser skiprows arg.

```
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as infile:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(infile):
        if line[:4] = 'Days':
            break

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=lineno)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas.io.parsers.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.io.parsers.read_csv). It has an option "skiprows". If your files always have the same 6 lines in the header, you could use skiprows=6

skiprows : list-like or integer
Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file
i.e.:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_cs("path/to/file.csv", sep=";", skiprows=6)
```

Comment: That is the Problem, Number of Non relevant data lines is not fixed.

Comment: In this case maybe you can try first to read all lines into a list and discard the lines you are not interested in. Than you could do pd.DataFrame.from_records()

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the variable in pandas read_csv.

In your case it would look like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file,header = 6 )
```

So your script will use the 6th line as the header and then start to read in the data...